# How to equalise sibling div heights?

Tags: css

```
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper"></div>
  <div class="content-wrapper"></div>
</div>
```

The height of `content-wrapper` is dynamic (`auto`). Is there any way to get the height of it and use it for the `sidebar-wrapper` so that it looks nice?

Comment: Have you tried [height: inherit;](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_dim_height.asp)?

Comment: Would `(min-)height: 100%;` be sufficient?

Comment: I think the question text is clear enough, if only people would read. `content-wrapper` has an automatic height, and `sidebar-wrapper` should get the same height. Not much unclear about it, although the wording may be a little peculiar.

Answer (score 5):

Displaying them like table cells would do it. Table cells can adjust their height automatically to the content, and all cells on the same row get the same height. If you give the side bar a fixed width (which is likely), you can easily get the content wrapper to fill the remaining space.

Whichever has the longest content will determine the height.

```css
.wrapper {
  width: 100%;
  display: table;
}
.sidebar-wrapper,
.content-wrapper {
  display: table-cell
}

.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: silver;
}

.content-wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="sidebar-wrapper">Here is <br>content<br>that is .....<br><br><br><br><br><br>Quite long</div>
<div class="content-wrapper">Smaller content</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Flexbox is an alternative to @GolezTrol's CSS tables.

```css
.wrapper {
  display: flex;
}
.sidebar-wrapper {
  width: 200px;
  background-color: silver;
}
.content-wrapper {
  background-color: yellow;
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">Here is
    <br>content
    <br>that is .....
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>
    <br>Quite long</div>
  <div class="content-wrapper">Smaller content</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just as nice, maybe even nicer.

Comment: Nice. Readers should be aware that flexbox isn't currently supported in <IE10 (http://caniuse.com/#feat=flexbox)